# Rails record query is taking forever and loading each record 1 by 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

Here's what the console looks like when I try to load the view:

[image]

and here's what my call looks like:

```
<% Review.where(product_id: product.id, shop_id: ShopifyAPI::Shop.current.id).limit(20).each do |review| %>
```

Even if I put a .limit on the query like I did above it still loads each record individually and takes a long time. I looked into .includes which is supposed to stop the N+1 queries but I can't use that (as far as I know) since the products come from the Shopify API (an active record collection I believe) and the reviews are the only thing that I have hosted in the database.

Can anbody give me some tips on how to fix this mess?

Comment: It's better to paste the actual log output text rather than an image. Also, please paste the rest of the code in the each do block. There is probably a count query inside the block that's causing the n+1.

Comment: I don't think n+1 is your problem.Look at the load times for each of those queries... almost everything is under 1.0ms, and the count queries are cached. At the bottom it adds up to 13781ms. There must be something higher up that's eating up time. If you can paste the entire log entry from the beginning of that request, it will help to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you need count of reviews from single query, Please use below query to fetch the count of reviews, and you can use the review_count attribute instead of review.count

```
Review.select('reviews.*, COUNT(reviews.id) as review_count').where(product_id: product.id, shop_id: ShopifyAPI::Shop.current.id).limit(20)
```

Please let me know if its working or not

Comment: I did this:

        <% Review.select('reviews.*, COUNT(reviews.id) as review_count').where(product_id: product.id, shop_id: ShopifyAPI::Shop.current.id).each do |review| %>

but it gives me an error:
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"reviews", :id=>nil

Comment: What record you get for this query `Review.select('reviews.*, COUNT(reviews.id) as review_count').where(product_id: product.id, shop_id: ShopifyAPI::Shop.current.id)` ? try to debug the code